# SitecoreIdentityServer service in AppPool getting stopped

Tags: sitecore-commerce, training-certification

[image][image]I am learning L300 module in sitecore commerce 9.0.2. By default there is habitat_master catalog in sitecore commerce (CMS) to create any eCommerce site. In L300 training module it is explained how to create a site in sitecore commerce. Sitecore commerce engine is extended in L300. There are 10 modules in L300. At the end of module 9 I got my habitat_master catalog missing. I found that my sitecoreidentityserver serivces in IIS are getting stopped whenever there is any request to sitecore commerce due to which i can not see habitat_catalog in CMS. Any idea why its happening and how to bring back habitat_master catalog??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to the community. It would be good if you be specific on your question and ask exactly what issue you are facing. This would help other member to get understand your question better and you will get your answer sooner.

Comment: I have edited my problem. hope it helps now.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the Event Log for more information, but I've seen this as a general issue with ASP.NET applications where requests to the application will cause the AppPool to stop because it's improperly configured.

Usually, it's that the AppPool is configured to run under a different account and that account either:

1. was deleted, or
2. has an incorrect password set in IIS

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dan on getting rid of frequent crash of appPool. Also do a system restart after this.
For bringing back the catalog refer- 
[Sitecore commerce storefront not showing catalog- [No catalog data available] and "Invalid catalog Id"](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15972/sitecore-commerce-storefront-not-showing-catalog-no-catalog-data-available-an)