# Sitecore commerce storefront not showing catalog- [No catalog data available] and "Invalid catalog Id"

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog, sxa-storefront

Today while working with Sitecore XC I landed up with storefront having No catalog data.
The error reads as -

```
26560 14:47:37 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.InvalidItemException
Message: Invalid catalog Id
Source: Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common
   at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStorefront.get_CatalogItem()
   at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Models.CommerceStorefront.get_Catalog()
   at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Catalog.Models.ProductLists.NamedSearch.GetProductEntities(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Catalog.Models.ProductLists.NamedSearch.GetProducts(Int32 pageSize, Int32 pageNumber)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Catalog.Repositories.PromotedProductsRepository.GetPromotedProductsJsonResult(IVisitorContext visitorContext, String productListId, String relationshipFieldId, String currentItemId, String currentCatalogItemId, Nullable`1 pageSize, Nullable`1 pageNumber)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Catalog.Controllers.CatalogController.GetPromotedProducts(Nullable`1 pageSize, Nullable`1 pageNumber, String productListsRawValue, String relationshipFieldId, String currentItemId, String currentCatalogItemId)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

The storefront site is loading but not showing any catalog items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that somehow the catalog details was reset in configuration template.

Steps :

- Open Commerce catalog configuration

> *"/sitecore/content/Sitecore/Storefront/Settings/Commerce/Catalog Configuration"*

- For default instance set value of catalog to

> Catalog : sitecore/content/Sitecore/Storefront/Home/Catalogs/Habitat_Master

- For 'Start Navigation Category'

> sitecore/content/Sitecore/Storefront/Home/Catalogs/Habitat_Master/Habitat_Master-Departments

Comment: If you see this settings in your configuration template and still having same issue, try this:
1. Recycle AppPool and check.
2. Re-indexing WEB
3. Commerce category has no broken link.
It worked for some people as per community comments.